# how to startActivityForResult() in a dialog to receive result in fragment.onActivityResult

Tags: android, start-activity, onactivityresult

I have a Fragment in which I call `this.startActivityForResult()`, the result arrives in this Fragment's `onActivityResult()` method and everthing works fine.

When I open a new `Dialog` in the same `Fragment`, how do I call `startActivityForResult()` in the Dialog to receive the result in the Fragment's `onActivityResult()` method as well?

```
getOwnerActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, NOTIFY_CODE); // doesn't work
```

Tried to send the Fragment's (`this`) to the dialog but I can't figure that out either.

-
..any help is highly appreciated!

EDIT: Code for opening the dialog

```
       btnNotify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                
                NotificationDialog ndialog = new NotificationDialog(v.getContext());
                ndialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                ndialog.setDialogResult(new NotificationDialog.OnMyDialogResult() {
                    @Override
                    public void finish(int dur) {
                        notifyDuration = dur;
                    }
                });
                ndialog.show();
        }
```

//  -- in the Dialog I want to call this

```
public void openNotifySel() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, getOwnerActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.label_dialog_notify));
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

??????????????.startActivityForResult(intent, NOTIFY_CODE);
        }
```

Comment: Can you paste the code for the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `MyFragmentName.this.startActivityForResult(intent, NOTIFY_CODE);`?

Comment: I get "MyFragment is not an enclosing class"

Comment: Did you replace the `MyFragmentName` with your fragment's name? Is `openNotifySel()` inside your fragment?

Comment: yes, it's called SettingsFragment actually. And I tried both calling SettingsFragment.this.openNotifySel(); and SettingsFragment.this.startActivityForResult(intent, NOTIFY_CODE); both doesn't compile

Comment: Can you put in your code for `SettingsFragment`? including the line were you inserted the `startActivityForResult()`. Thanks

Comment: it's in the post openNotifySel(). it works calling it in the fragment (replacing ??? with this) not sure how to call that method from the dialog

Comment: I found many posts with this issue and there seems to be no easy answer. I decided to work around and change the UI a bit. thank you anyway.